# Get the formatted text from EA elements notes

Tags: c#, element, enterprise-architect

I am working on Enterprise Architect Add-In for creating requirements element through automation. In the element notes of EA when bold, underlined and hyperlink options are used ,they appear in DataGridView as shown below.

```
Example of <b>bold</b> , <u>underlined .</u> The image hyperlink is <a href="$imageman://id=1126108845;mdg=Global;name=Exception.bmp;type=Bitmap;"><font color="#0000ff"><u>Exception.bmp</u></font></a>
```

Similar problem occurs if we write it to Excel as well. How to get formatted text from EA element notes instead of Html Tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Repository.GetFormatFromField(string Format, string Text)`

From the [manual](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/automation/repository3.html):

> String
>
> Notes: After accessing a field that contains formatting, use this
> method to convert it to your preferred format; returns the field in
> the format specified.
>
> Parameters:
>
> Format: String - The format to convert the field to; valid formats
> are:
> -  HTML - Full HTML
> -  RTF - Rich Text Format
> -  TXT - Plain text
>
> Text: String - The field to be converted

Now how to get RTF or HTML formatted text into Excel or a another target is an entirely different question, which I'm sure already exists on StackOverflow.

Comment: You should as well look into the corresponding `Set` operation.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Thank you..I tried using  string formattedNotes = Session.Repository.GetFormatFromField("TXT", Note); It removes the html tags but the text is not formatted as bold or underlined.

Comment: That is what the `TXT` parameter is supposed to do. How did you expect plain text to contain formatting?

Comment: yes..I tried using HTML also..but when it is writing to excel or displayed in datagridview, all the tags appear in the sentence like this : <b>bold </b><u>underlined </u><i>italic</i>..is it possible to get the actual bold and underlined text in excel without the html tags..

Comment: You'll have to do some research on how to get the formatted text into Excel or another applications. There often are many ways to do that, some requiring specific libraries.